# Java Character issue fix, but want to understand how the wrong data was generated

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding

Attempting to insert a string like this into the Oracle table : ABčDE

The Oracle table is defined like as :

```
SQL> create table DUMMY_TEST (Field1 number, Name_Test varchar2(20));
```

The following is the Java/JDBC code being used. It does 2 Inserts. 
One Insert is hard-coded into the code and the 2nd is retrieved from a file.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Locale;


class JdbcTest
{
    static StringBuffer sbuff = new StringBuffer();

    public static void main (String a[])
    {
        //Creating the connection
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//server:port/ServiceName";
        String user = "xa21appdb";
        String pass = "neptune";

        //Inserting data using SQL query
        String sql = "INSERT INTO DUMMY_TEST VALUES(1, 'ABèDE')";

        loadDataFromFile();

        Connection con=null;
        try
        {
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());

            //Reference to connection interface
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);

            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            System.out.println("Executing 1st INSERT");
            int m = st.executeUpdate(sql);
            if (m == 1)
                System.out.println("1st inserted successfully ");
            else
                System.out.println("1st insertion failed");

            System.out.println("Executing 2nd INSERT");
            m = st.executeUpdate(sbuff.toString());
            if (m == 1)
                System.out.println("2nd inserted successfully ");
            else
                System.out.println("2nd insertion failed");

            con.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }

    static void loadDataFromFile()
    {
        try
        {
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("/tmp/input.txt");
         Reader      inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader( inputStream, "UTF-8");

            int ch = inputStreamReader.read();

            while(ch != -1)
            {
                sbuff.append((char) ch);
                ch = inputStreamReader.read();
            }
            inputStreamReader.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
```

Here is the content of the file which holds the same SQL as the hard-coded value.

```
> cat /tmp/input.txt
INSERT INTO DUMMY_TEST VALUES(2, 'ABèDE')
```

To ensure both the hard-coded SQL and the SQL from the file are the same, the xxd command was used to show the hex values.

This only shows the INSERT statement along with the ABčDE string to be inserted.

```
> xxd -b JdbcTest.java
    :
    :
000019e: 01101100 00100000 00111101 00100000 00100010 01001001  l = "I
00001a4: 01001110 01010011 01000101 01010010 01010100 00100000  NSERT
00001aa: 01001001 01001110 01010100 01001111 00100000 01000100  INTO D
00001b0: 01010101 01001101 01001101 01011001 01011111 01010100  UMMY_T
00001b6: 01000101 01010011 01010100 00100000 01010110 01000001  EST VA
00001bc: 01001100 01010101 01000101 01010011 00101000 00110001  LUES(1
00001c2: 00101100 00100000 00100111 01000001 01000010 11101000  , 'AB.
00001c8: 01000100 01000101 00100111 00101001 00100010 00111011  DE')";
```

This shows the entire file code which is being read with the ABčDE string to be inserted.

```
> xxd -b /tmp/input.txt
0000000: 01001001 01001110 01010011 01000101 01010010 01010100  INSERT
0000006: 00100000 01001001 01001110 01010100 01001111 00100000   INTO
000000c: 01000100 01010101 01001101 01001101 01011001 01011111  DUMMY_
0000012: 01010100 01000101 01010011 01010100 00100000 01010110  TEST V
0000018: 01000001 01001100 01010101 01000101 01010011 00101000  ALUES(
000001e: 00110010 00101100 00100000 00100111 01000001 01000010  2, 'AB
0000024: 11101000 01000100 01000101 00100111 00101001 00001010  .DE').
```

When comparing the 2 file, it confirms the string is identical between the hard-code and the file.

```
00100111 01000001 01000010 11101000 01000100 01000101 00100111
   '        A         B       .        D        E         '
```

When the code is run, the following 2 rows get inserted into Oracle.

```
SQL> select * from dummy_test;

    FIELD1 NAME_TEST
---------- --------------------
         1 ABèDE
         2 AB?DE
```

Using the DUMP command to get the details for each.

```
SQL> select field1,  dump(name_test, 1016) from dummy_test;

    FIELD1   DUMP(NAME_TEST,1016)
----------   -------------------------------------------------------------
         1   Typ=1 Len=6 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: 41,42,c4,8d,44,45
         2   Typ=1 Len=7 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: 41,42,ef,bf,bd,44,45
```

If the code is modified from this :

```
Reader      inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader( inputStream, "UTF-8");
```

to this :

```
Reader      inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader( inputStream);
```

It works as both rows will show the following :

```
SQL> select field1,  dump(name_test, 1016) from dummy_test;

    FIELD1   DUMP(NAME_TEST,1016)
----------   -------------------------------------------------------------
         1   Typ=1 Len=6 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: 41,42,c4,8d,44,45
         2   Typ=1 Len=6 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: 41,42,c4,8d,44,45
```

Now for the 3 questions.

1 - In the scenario when it works and the "special" character is inserted properly, this can be confirmed because the Oracle characterset AL32UTF8 shows that c4 8d represents č but my question is why does Oracle print out è.

2 - When the UTF-8 is used with the READER, 3 bytes (ef,bf,bd) are being inserted. 
If I did my UTF-8 calculations properly it comes to something like the following :

```
‭11101111‬  ‭10111111‬  ‭10111101‬
1111‬111111‬111101‬
FF FD
```

And that is a very unusual character.

Although I understand there was a conflict with the conversion but can you explain exactly what happened?

Edited to add a 3rd question.

3 - My Putty session has the characterset set to : ISO-8859-1:1998 (Latin-1, West Europe)
Why do I see a ABèDE instead of ABčDE at the command prompt?

Comment: I can now answer #1. The Putty session itself was set to 8859-1. Once changed to 8859-13, it would show the correct character. Actually, this probably answers both #1 & #3.